# Can not boot into my windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, usb

I have two drives. One drive has `windows 7` and the other has `XP`. I created an ubuntu live USB-stick with `rufus` to see if my computer can handle, because it is very old.

Specs:
Pentium 4 2.8 GHz 2 GB ddr 256 MB GPU

It could not load from USB.

It was doing [this](https://www.google.com.tr/search?q=freecom+version+0.84-pre2+xms+swap&oq=freecom+version&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l3.9321j0j4&client=tablet-android-samsung&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8#q=ubuntu+freecom+version+0.84-pre2+xms+swap)

So I restarted, but I can't get into my `windows`. I disabled each HDD but it comes to always grub menu.

I am on tablet, sorry for mistakes.

[image]

As you can see in the image, it always come here.

I have 2 GB USB-stick which I used for ubuntu.

I also have xubuntu install CD but it also could not install.

I have 1 TB external, 16 GB 8 GB flash. My internal HDD's are 160 GB and 80 GB. I can sacrifice my `XP` but I need `windows 7` in 160 GB. Can I save them and if so how?

I also disabled enabled boot from CD and USB but still this menu.

I need to use `android studio` so `XP` gave errors because of `JDK` so I wanted to use linux with this old system. `Windows 7` is freezing so linux can be the solution to solve this for me, but you see my problems :(

I did not change anything since I started this post.

Now it is showing this:

[image]

When i try to install xubuntu from cd booting, error is :

[Xubntu boot error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nErjm.jpg)

Comment: You have a disabled hard disk, did you do that and forget to enable it again?