# Which Ubuntu can run my old machine?

Tags: 14.04

You can see my system specs here

http://speccy.piriform.com/results/1OwYBS1DNyFTxrOXiAe0rzF

```
CPU
Intel Pentium 4
Northwood 0.13um Technology
RAM
2.00GB Dual-Channel DDR @ 200MHz (3-3-3-8)
Motherboard
Gigabyte Technology Co. Ltd. 8IPE1000-G/L (Socket 478): 
22 °C
Graphics
aidata 725BF (1024x768@85Hz)
256MB NVIDIA GeForce FX 5500 (Undefined)
Storage
74GB SAMSUNG SP0802N ATA Device (ATA):
```

I am having problem with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, and Xubuntu. I can't install them.

Which can I install?

Comment: Please describe what problems you have. All Ubuntu flavours are similar except for the desktop environment. If they have issues with your hardware, this will be very likely a problem for all available versions, but maybe it can be fixed.

Comment: If you would tell us what problem you are having in installation, we can help you!

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/771344/can-not-boot-into-my-windows those kinds of events.

Comment: According to the system specifications provided, you should be able to run Ubuntu 16.04 LTS or Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, but only 32-bit editions. Please ensure that you have downloaded a 32-bit edition of Ubuntu.  If you are already using a 32-bit edition of Ubuntu, please provide us with more details (error messages, ...) about the problem you are facing, so that we can help you.

Comment: You can try Xubuntu 14.04 32 bit. As previously mentioned, we need more details/ error logs / messages.  Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar)

Answer (score 2):

I Think that the best [Ubuntu flavour](http://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/flavours) for you is the [Xubuntu](http://www.xubuntu.org/), wich is Ubuntu + XFCE Desktop Environment. 
Because it's lightweight and have a good visual(compared to others light Desktop environments).

Answer (score 1):

You should really try Lubuntu (https://lubuntu.net/), in my own experience it's one the lightest Ubuntu official flavours. I installed it succesfully in computers with <= 2Gb and it runs pretty well.
By looking at you computer specs, you should probably go with the 32 bit version.